# CUDA Branching Optimization

Tags: cuda

I've got a program that uses a few CUDA kernels and this one is taking 50-100ms to run while the others take 0-5ms. I expect this has something to do with all the branching, but I'm not really sure how to reduce it. I'm compiling for a compute capability 2.1 device. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
// chosen using occupancy spreadsheet
#define SCORE_THREADS_PER_BLOCK 448

__device__ double ScoringMatrixVal(double *scoring_matrix, size_t pitch, unsigned int row, unsigned int column) {
  return *((double*)((char*) scoring_matrix + row * pitch) + column);
}

__global__ void ScoreBindingSites(char *input_sequence, unsigned long is_length, unsigned int *rvd_sequence, unsigned int rs_len, double cutoff, unsigned int rvd_num, double *scoring_matrix, size_t sm_pitch, unsigned char *results) {

  int block_seq_index = SCORE_THREADS_PER_BLOCK * (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x);
  int thread_id = (blockDim.x * threadIdx.y) + threadIdx.x;
  int seq_index = block_seq_index + thread_id;

  if (seq_index < 1 || seq_index >= is_length || seq_index + rs_len >= is_length - 1) return;

  if (input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 'T' || input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 't') {

    double thread_result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rs_len; i++) {

      int rvd_index = i;

      int sm_col = 4;

      char base = input_sequence[seq_index + i];

      if (base == 'A' || base == 'a')    
        sm_col = 0;
      if (base == 'C' || base == 'c')
        sm_col = 1;
      if (base == 'G' || base == 'g')
        sm_col = 2;
      if (base == 'T' || base == 't')
        sm_col = 3;

      thread_result += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index], sm_col);

    }

    results[seq_index] |= (thread_result < cutoff ? 1UL : 0UL) << (2 * rvd_num);

  } 

  if (input_sequence[seq_index + rs_len] == 'A' || input_sequence[seq_index + rs_len] == 'a') {

    double thread_result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rs_len; i++) {

      int rvd_index = rs_len - i - 1;

      int sm_col = 4;

      char base = input_sequence[seq_index + i];

      if (base == 'A' || base == 'a')    
        sm_col = 3;
      if (base == 'C' || base == 'c')
        sm_col = 2;
      if (base == 'G' || base == 'g')
        sm_col = 1;
      if (base == 'T' || base == 't')
        sm_col = 0;

      thread_result += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index], sm_col);

    }

    results[seq_index] |= (thread_result < cutoff ? 1UL : 0UL) << (2 * rvd_num + 1);

  }

}
```

ScoreBindingSites is launched with (32, 14) threads per block and enough blocks to cover the input sequence. The full source can be found [here](https://github.com/njbooher/boglab_tfcount/blob/b7ace0823fcf8dc6f97d3f33fd5db1691b643be8/tfcount_cuda.cu) if that would be helpful.

Comment: Your problem is much more likely to be related to memory access than branching. That kernel is doing uncoalesced, byte sized global memory loads, which will be horribly inefficient. CUDA ships with a profiler on every platform that is supported. I recommend you familiarise yourself with one and use it to study the codes performance in more detail.

Comment: I've used the profiler. At some point the "Kernel Memory" analysis started freezing between the 5th and 10th run and I don't know why. But the "Kernel Instruction" analysis reports divergence as an issue now. Another reason I expect it's not memory access is because early versions of this kernel with bad memory access the kernel might take several seconds. Now as far as I can tell for any given load from input_sequence all threads in a warp are loading consecutive bytes resulting in one transaction, and  the execution time is significantly better. Scoring matrix should fit in cache.

Comment: How long is `rs_len` generally?  Maybe you could load chunks of input_sequence into shared memory.  Since every thread is accessing very local parts of the input sequence you should get a lot of reuse. But those byte-sized accesses generally appear to have good locality contrary to @talonmies' comment. The ScoringMatrix accesses are likely to be uncoalesced though, so anything you can do to improve their locality may help.  Branchine may be a problem if there is lots of divergence in the outer if statements, which there probably is for genetic sequences...

Comment: @harrism `rs_len` is between 12 and 32. I'll try out the suggestions tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: While you are at it you might consider combining the 'T' and 'A' loops [like this](https://gist.github.com/5fe0572ba6dd2fe64aac)

Comment: @harrism Rewriting the loop as suggested was a small gain over several calls. [Loading the sequence into shared memory](https://gist.github.com/ba4c722b66e1e943eaf0) didn't seem to help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to improve this code:

- As has been suggested above, merge the two loops for `'T'` and `'A'`. This is probably your greatest source of branch divergence as the small cascade of `if`-statements inside the loop will very probably be compiled as predicated instructions (see Section 5.4.2 of the [NVidia CUDA C Programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf)).
- Byte-sized global memory access is a terrible idea. Instead, I would suggest declaring `input_sequence`, `results` and `base` as `char4` and, in each iteration of your main loop, do your thing for each value of `base.x`, `base.y`, `base.z` and `base.w`.
- You may also want to have a closer look at what `ScoringMatrixVal` is doing. Is it just reading values from memory? If so, could you replace it with constant memory? Or a texture?

**Update**

As requested, here is what I meant with the second point. I haven't tested the code, though, so feel free to keep any bugs or typos you find. Note that I've assumed, for simplicity, that `rs_len` is a multiple of four.

```
// chosen using occupancy spreadsheet
#define SCORE_THREADS_PER_BLOCK 448

__device__ double ScoringMatrixVal(double *scoring_matrix, size_t pitch, unsigned int row, unsigned int column) {
  return scoring_matrix[ row*pitch/sizeof(double) + column ];
}

__global__ void ScoreBindingSites(char4 *input_sequence, unsigned long is_length, unsigned int *rvd_sequence, unsigned int rs_len, double cutoff, unsigned int rvd_num, double *scoring_matrix, size_t sm_pitch, unsigned char *results) {

  int block_seq_index = SCORE_THREADS_PER_BLOCK * (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x);
  int thread_id = (blockDim.x * threadIdx.y) + threadIdx.x;
  int seq_index = block_seq_index + thread_id;

  if (seq_index < 1 || seq_index >= is_length || seq_index + rs_len >= is_length - 1) return;

  if (input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 'T' || input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 't') {

    double4 thread_result = make_double4( 0 );

    for (int i = 0; i < rs_len/4; i++) {

      int rvd_index = 4*i;

      int4 sm_col = make_int4( 4 );

      char4 base = input_sequence[seq_index + i];

      if (base.x == 'A' || base.x == 'a')    
        sm_col.x = 0;
      else if (base.x == 'C' || base.x == 'c')
        sm_col.x = 1;
      else if (base.x == 'G' || base.x == 'g')
        sm_col.x = 2;
      else if (base.x == 'T' || base.x == 't')
        sm_col.x = 3;
      thread_result.x += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index + 0], sm_col.x);

      if (base.y == 'A' || base.y == 'a')    
        sm_col.y = 0;
      else if (base.y == 'C' || base.y == 'c')
        sm_col.y = 1;
      else if (base.y == 'G' || base.y == 'g')
        sm_col.y = 2;
      else if (base.y == 'T' || base.y == 't')
        sm_col.y = 3;
      thread_result.y += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index + 1], sm_col.y);

      if (base.z == 'A' || base.z == 'a')    
        sm_col.z = 0;
      else if (base.z == 'C' || base.z == 'c')
        sm_col.z = 1;
      else if (base.z == 'G' || base.z == 'g')
        sm_col.z = 2;
      else if (base.z == 'T' || base.z == 't')
        sm_col.z = 3;
      thread_result.z += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index + 2], sm_col.z);

      if (base.w == 'A' || base.w == 'a')    
        sm_col.w = 0;
      else if (base.w == 'C' || base.w == 'c')
        sm_col.w = 1;
      else if (base.w == 'G' || base.w == 'g')
        sm_col.w = 2;
      else if (base.w == 'T' || base.w == 't')
        sm_col.w = 3;
      thread_result.w += ScoringMatrixVal(scoring_matrix, sm_pitch, rvd_sequence[rvd_index + 3], sm_col.w);

    }

    double acc_thread_result = thread_result.x + thread_result.y + thead_result.z + thread_result.w;

    results[seq_index] |= (acc_thread_result < cutoff ? 1UL : 0UL) << (2 * rvd_num);

  }

  if (input_sequence[seq_index + rs_len] == 'A' || input_sequence[seq_index + rs_len] == 'a') {

    ...

  }

}
```

A few notes:

- I've re-written, hopefully correctly, your function `ScoringMatrixVal` to use regular array access, as the whole mess with pointer arithmetic may be throwing the compiler off.
- I've converted your `if`-statements to a cascade of `if-elseif`-statements, as they seem mutually exclusive. I'm guessing the compiler will use predicated instructions and will interleave the four `if-elseif` blocks.
- You may consider replacing all this with a `char[256]` where everything is set to `4` except for the character codes at `A`, `a`, `C`, `c`, etc...
- If you convert the `if-elseif`-statements to a table lookup, you could use two different tables for `input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 'T'` and `input_sequence[seq_index + rs_len] == 'A'`, thus keeping it all in one loop.

I hope I haven't messed-up the code too much and that this helps!

Comment: It's pretty clear that each thread will be accessing different locations in ScoringMatrixVal, so __constant__ memory would lead to serialization.

Comment: @harrism: Are you sure? The calls between threads differ only in the last argument, which is in [0,3], e.g. at most four different offsets. In any case, I was offering suggestions which the OP should try out and see what works best for him/her.

Comment: Can you explain point 2 in more detail? As written it sounds like the input sequence would be broken up into 4 char wide blocks that would make access strided. The closest thing I came up with today was [each thread loading 4 bytes into shared memory at a time](https://gist.github.com/000d9b57b4efff644199), but that didn't seem to improve performance any. For point 3, the scoring matrix is constant, and has 5 columns, 4 for legit bases, and a 5th for junk in the sequence. I tried loading it into shared memory today and it didn't help, but I'll try texture memory tomorrow.

Comment: @Pedro constant cache is optimized for broadcasting the same value to all threads in a warp. So if threads within a warp access different constant memory addresses, they get serialized (it's sort of the opposite of shared memory).  njbooher says the matrix has only 5 columns, but he provides no info about the number of rows.

Comment: @harrism: Right, but if the table is smaller than 64k, it will fit in the constant cache, and since all threads access the same row, it will serialize to at most 4 reads *from cache*, which should still be faster than a global memory fetch.

Comment: @Pedro: the constant **cache** is only 8kb, the total constant memory size is 64kb. Constant memory serialization is a pretty insidious performance loss - serialization + cache miss even more so. I don't think I have ever seen a usage case where even "semi uniform access" of constant memory out performed textures or global memory access through the L1 cache.

Comment: @talonmies: Well, this would make an interesting test-case then.

Comment: @djmj: I would assume that the compiler translates this to `rs_len >> 2`. What I'm hoping will improve the kernel is the number of reads from global memory. Or am I completely misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: +1 for the lookup table in constant memory, and `rs_len/4` == `rs_len * 0.25f` but it won't change much performance

Comment: Nono, the lookup table is the best idea here I think. But your bitshift is superior to my multiplication :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. I'll try it out in a few, but I just wanted to mention that the original ScoringMatrixVal formula came from the documentation for [cudaMallocPitch](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html)

Comment: I'm still working through some of the suggestions, but as far as converting the if-statements into if-elseif goes, that actually resulted in 25% runtime increase.

Comment: @njbooher: Wow, that's not too good. Then I'd really suggest replacing the `if`-statements with an array lookup!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood in your kernel each Thread reads up to 32 characters and checks each char and outputs some data.

You could completely remove the loop by implicit simulating it using a different block approach and different indexing (If that is possible in your case).

Each block has 32 threads where each thread calculates the result of one loop iteration.

I don't know if its faster but a test worth.

Pedro's answer using a table-lookup to replace your conditions should definetly be taken into consideration.

**Minor changes:**

Is `input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 'T' || input_sequence[seq_index - 1] == 't'` optimized to just one memory read?

Save a register by removing only once-used variable `threadId`.

Comment: The compiler will do those minor changes automatically, i.e. it probably won't even create a local variable for `threadId`. You may need to add the `__restrict__` keyword to the parameter `input_sequence` though.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at `__restrict__`. Since once declaring a temporary object outside of a loop in Java and gaining 25% performance gain I don't trust compilers anymore :D

Comment: Actually, that was probably the compiler not trusting you... ;)